# Add event listener to every Component with a given property

Tags: reactjs

I have a lot of Components with `onKeyup` event listeners, which then check to see if the key was `Tab` and if so, take an action. I'd like to abstract that a bit and create an `onTab` property, where the value is a callback function that executes that action. But, importantly, I'd like the "was this key a `Tab`?" logic to be abstracted away. My thought was that I could write logic that said "When initializing this Component, check if it has an `onTab` property, and if so, create an `onKeyup` event listener with X logic to trigger the `onTab` callback." However, I'm unsure how to do that.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 solutions, each with its advantages and complexity.

First, use hook:

```
// use-on-tab.js

const useOnTab = function (callback) {
  let listener = function (event) {
    if (event.code === 'Enter') {
      callback()
    }
  }

  return listener
}

export default useOnTab
```

```
// Foo.js

import useOnTab from './use-on-tab'

const Foo = function () {
  let onTab = useOnTab(() => console.log('foo'))
  return <div onKeyUp={onTab} tabIndex="0">Foo</div>
}

export default Foo
```

This solution is quite simple, you can hide the logic of checking key and only pass the callback. But you still have to manually call `useOnTab` and add `onKeyUp` prop on every components.

---

Second, use HOC:

```
// with-on-tab.js

const withOnTab = function (WrappedComponent) {
  let createListener = function (callback) {
    return function (event) {
      if (event.code === 'Enter') {
        callback()
      }
    }
  }

  return function ({ onTab, ...props }) {
    return <WrappedComponent {...props} onKeyUp={createListener(onTab)} />
  }
}

export default withOnTab
```

```
// Bar.js

import withOnTab from './with-on-tab'

const Bar = function (props) {
  return <div tabIndex="0" {...props}>Bar</div>
}

export default withOnTab(Bar)
```

```
<Bar onTab={() => console.log('bar')} />
```

Read more about [Higher-Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).

---

And the last one is custom JSX:

```js
// jsx-dev-runtime.js

import * as ReactJSXRuntimeDev from 'react/jsx-dev-runtime'

export const Fragment = ReactJSXRuntimeDev.Fragment

export function jsxDEV(
  type,
  props,
  key,
  isStaticChildren,
  source,
  self
) {
  let newProps = props

  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(props, 'onTab')) {
    let { onTab, ...props } = newProps

    newProps = {
      ...props,
      onKeyUp: event => {
        if (event.code === 'Enter') {
          onTab()
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return ReactJSXRuntimeDev.jsxDEV(
    type,
    newProps,
    key,
    isStaticChildren,
    source,
    self
  )
}
```

```
// Baz.js

const Baz = function (props) {
  return <div tabIndex="0" {...props}>Baz</div>
}

export default Baz
```

```
/** @jsxImportSource custom-jsx-library */

<Baz onTab={() => console.log('baz')} />
```

I get this idea from `@emotion/react` which has to deal with the `css` prop. [Github](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/tree/main/packages/react/src)